# Should we create a MATLAB new community?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-recommendation, community

In the Stack Overflow community I see many questions related to MATLAB programs. I use both it and Mathematica for work, and I see that Mathematica has a separate community for its questions, that are always related to solve a problem with it or to do something with it.

Considering that MATLAB is a specific program, like Mathematica, Joomla, Drupal and so on, it can be useful to create a new community for it, or it's better to continue to ask questions of Stack Overflow community?

Answer (score 6):

There is already a proposal for [MATLAB](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106196/matlab) in Area 51. You can follow and contribute to the proposal.

Read the [Area 51 FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) for more details.